# Unsure how to remedy 'std::out_of_range' error

Tags: c++, string, vector, find, fstream

Working on a program that is given a list like separated by "," and putting the contents into a vector.

Test.txt contains:

> "45001524","MOCHI ICE CREAM BONBONS","LI","19022128593","G. T. Japan, Inc.","2017-11-15 19:19:38","2017-11-15 19:19:38","ICE CREAM INGREDIENTS: MILK, CREAM, SUGAR, STRAWBERRIES (STRAWBERRIES, SUGAR), CORN SYRUP SOLIDS, SKIM MILK, WHEY, NATURAL FLAVOR, GUAR GUM, MONO & DIGLYCERIDES, BEET JUICE AND BEET POWDER (FOR COLOR), CELLULOSE GUM, LOCUST BEAN GUM, CARRAGEENAN. COATING INGREDIENTS: SUGAR, WATER, RICE FLOUR, TREHALOSE, EGG WHITES, BEET JUICE AND BEET POWDER (FOR COLOR), DUSTED WITH CORN & POTATO STARCH"

Function readFile is being passed that test.txt, having already been opened, and is trying to import each "," separated string into a struct of 8 string types. The Struct's name is itemType.

int itemNumber is the count.

```
void readFile( ifstream& inFile, vector<itemType>& item, int& itemNumber)
{


string currentLine;
int indexDef = 0;

while(getline(inFile, currentLine) && itemNumber < MAX_DB_SIZE){

    indexDef = 0;
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].NDBNumber);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].longName);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].dataSource);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].upc);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].manufacturer);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].dataModified);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].dataAvailable);
    getQuotedString(currentLine, indexDef, item[itemNumber].ingredients);
}

}

bool  getQuotedString( string& line, int& index, string& subString)
{
    int endIndex;
    //Start at 1st ' " '
    endIndex = index;
    //Find the next ' " '
    index = line.find('"', index+1);
    //subString = the characters between the first ' " ' and the second ' " '
    subString = line.substr(endIndex+1, index-endIndex-1);

    cout << subString << endl;

    //Move the second ' " ' over 2, passing over the comma and setting it on the next "
    index = index+2;
}
```

I'm using the `cout << subString` for testing.

Its outputting everything perfectly as I want it, but after the last output it throws an error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure it out :\ I think my index is overflowing the file's length, but Im unsure how to remedy it.

Comment: Catch the exception when running in a debugger, to locate where in your code it happens. Check the indexes used, and compare to the string they are used on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a max DB size of 30000, and the read file terminates are file end of 30000, and vector<itemType> item(MAX_DB_SIZE); is the initation, so I don't think thats the problem?

Comment: You never increment `itemNumber`. If you use `std::vector` as the dynamic container it is, you don't need to keep track of the number of elements manually.

Comment: @molbdnilo In this situation test.txt only has 1 itemNumber, in the actual input there are a few thousands lines that all look like test.txt, and for ever new line it gets incremented. Should that matter here, since this is all supposed to work on a per line basis, and its failing a 1 line attempt I believe its something else?

Comment: I've added an
if(index >= line.length())
else{

around the substring = line.substr(endIndex+1, index-endIndex-1);

Now I am getting a terminate instance of std::bad_alloc

@Someprogrammerdude

Any thoughts? Thanks guys

Comment: @Caram2 Where is the code that increments for each line? It's not in the loop that reads all the lines.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm the biggest dumbass in existance and I thank you all for your patience in that I wasn't incrementing itemNumber. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: I think this should be closed as typo then.

Answer (score 1):

Some moron wasn't incrementing his itemNumber. Adding itemNumber++ to void readFile solved the problems and it is now reading appropriately.